# A Specific URL-Rewriting Situation

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm trying to achieve this on my Apache2 server:

anytime a url like this is entered:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/first_location
```

mod_rewrite should redirect to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/first_location/first_location.php
```

where "first_location" may be any valid folder name.

I have been able to glean this much:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-]/ .......
```

but not sure how to handle the redirect url part for this situation.

Appreciate any help to complete the substitution part (and also correct the pattern part if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `first_location` is a valid folder, there's an apache module called **mod_dir** which will automatically redirect the browser to the same folder but with a trailing slash. So you can either turn off **mod_dir** by using `DirectorySlash Off`, or allow the redirect and just match against a trailing slash. So you'd want something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# check that it's a valid folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# check that the php file actually exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%1.php -f
# rewrite
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/$ /$1/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I coped and pasted this in a fresh .htaccess file but it gives me a 500 error. I've checked the apache config file and mod_dir load command is uncommented (so active).

Comment: @user1729972 You need to check that mod_rewrite is uncommented as well

Comment: Oh it most certainly is. mod_rewrite works for other things, specifically not this.

Comment: @user1729972 Seems like I'm missing a close paren, try it again